# make drop down card smooth animation with tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a drop down menu with tailwind but for some reason I'm only able to make the opacity work not the height smoothness. what's wrong?

this is the react component code below. this should be simple yet I can't make it work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import LazyImage from './LazyImage';

export default function ProjectCard({ isOrientationStart, project }) {
  const [isExpand, setIsExpand] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-dark-slate m-10 rounded-3xl p-5 duration-300 hover:bg-opacity-80 hover:scale-90'>
      <h1 className='text-white font-bold text-xl'>{project.title}</h1>
      <div
        className={`flex flex-col transition-all duration-500 ease-out ${
          isOrientationStart ? 'md:flex-row' : 'md:flex-row-reverse'
        } w-full justify-center items-center ${
          isExpand ? 'h-full opacity-100' : 'h-0 opacity-0 overflow-hidden'
        }`}>
        <div className='grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 max-w-sm p-6 rounded-xl'>
          <LazyImage
            className='rounded-xl border-4 border-orange'
            src={project.img1}
            alt='Project image 1'
          />
          <LazyImage
            className='rounded-xl border-4 border-orange'
            src={project.img2}
            alt='Project image 2'
          />
          <LazyImage
            className='rounded-xl border-4 border-orange'
            src={project.img3}
            alt='Project image 3'
          />
          <LazyImage
            className='rounded-xl border-4 border-orange'
            src={project.img4}
            alt='Project image 4'
          />
        </div>
        <div className='text-black font-extralight text-lg p-10 bg-zinc-300 rounded-xl'>
          <p>{project.description}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i
        onClick={() => setIsExpand(!isExpand)}
        className={`fa-solid cursor-pointer fa-chevron-down text-4xl duration-500 hover:scale-110 hover:animate-bounce ${
          isExpand ? 'text-white' : 'text-orange'
        }`}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to achieve smooth height transitions using tailwind you will need to add the height property to the transitions in your tailwind.config.js file. You should be able to edit your config file like so:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      transitionProperty: {
        'height': 'height',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

after doing this check to see if the height is transitioning as well. If not you might need to add the property on the div in your jsx like so:

```
<div 
  className={`flex flex-col transition-all transition-[height] duration-500 ease-out
  <-- ... -->
>
```

Here is the tailwind docs for reference [Tailwind Transitions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property#customizing-your-theme)

I will set up a repo to test this out. Let me know if this works.